# Typescript: The type of TextNode

Tags: typescript, dom, textnode, child-nodes, dom-node

If you write below code:

```js
const e = document.body.firstChild;
if (e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
    console.log(e.data);
```

You will get this error on `e.data`:

> TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ChildNode'.

While if the condition be true (`e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE`) then `e` has some other properties in addition to regular `ChildNode` properties, like **`data`** and **`wholeText`**.

---

What type should I cast to (other than `any`)?

Comment: great Q.  surprised it (and the A) don't have a thousand up-votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should write your condinition based on `nodeName`, hence it will return "#text" for text nodes.

[nodeName Example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName#Example)

**The interface what you are looking for in TypeScript is `CharacterData` or simply `Text`.** On the `Text` interface you will have both the `data` and `wholeText` properties since it implements the `characterData` interface. On the `characterData` abstract interface you only have the `data` prop.

[Character​Data (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData)

[Text (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text)

Comment: But I didn't write the condition based on `tagName`. I wrote it based on `nodeType`. Anyway, you answered my question. Thanks.